# Parsing RSS feed with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rss

I'm trying to get [rss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss) to work with node, but it does nothing for me.
Sorry for such a noob question, I've been struggling with this for a while.

Here's my server.js

```html
var express = require('express'),
 app = express(),
 server = require('http').createServer(app),
 RSS = require('rss')

server.listen(3000);

app.set('views', __dirname, 'views');
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

 
/* lets create an rss feed */
var feed = new RSS({
    title: 'Feed',
    feed_url: 'https://www.rt.com/rss/',
    site_url: 'https://www.rt.com/',
    language: 'en'

});
 
/* loop over data and add to feed */
feed.item({
    title:  'item title',
    // description: 'use this for the content. It can include html.',
    // url: 'https://www.rt.com/rss/', // link to the item 
    // guid: '1123', // optional - defaults to url 
});
 
// cache the xml to send to clients 
var xml = feed.xml();
```

And here's my index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Feed</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Feed</h1>
<div id="content"></div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var content = <%= feed.item %>;

    var  <%= feed.item %> = "true";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run `node server.js`, there's only the h1 title in the index page.

Comment: Well, your .html only has one `<h1>`. You're not looping through any items. You also only added one item to the feed. What's the problem.

Comment: Right. How can get the feed showing up in the index page?

Comment: Why are you even using javascript here? Like, assigning something to `content` and other stuff. This does not make sense. Just print out the content into the `.html`

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what do you mean.

Comment: Okay, sorry to hear that.

Comment: `rss` is for creating feeds not parsing them. This might be more helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser